# JavaFX: how to recognise current row in TableView?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

[People Table - TableView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7wjP.png)

I've built a TableView in JavaFX as shown in the image (People Table) consisting of a list of names. How can I have the first and last name printed to console on the corresponding row every time the 'details' button is clicked?

(For reference my final goal and original unanswered question is for the details button to open a template scene and to populate it with data for that specific person).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class cutExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }


  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("People");

    // create a table.
    final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(
      FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown")
      )
    );

    // define the table columns.
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> actionCol = new TableColumn<>("Action");
    actionCol.setSortable(false);


    // create a cell value factory with a details button for each row in the table.
    actionCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {
      @Override public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> personBooleanTableColumn) {
        return new AddPersonCell(stage, table);
      }
    });

    table.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, actionCol);
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
    stage.show();
  }

  /** A table cell containing a button for details on each person. */
  private class AddPersonCell extends TableCell<Person, Boolean> {
    // a button for a specific person's details
    final Button details       = new Button("Details");
    // pads and centers the button in the cell.
    final StackPane paddedButton = new StackPane();


    /**
     * AddPersonCell constructor
     * @param stage the stage in which the table is placed.
     * @param table the table to which a new person can be added.
     */
    AddPersonCell(final Stage stage, final TableView table) {
      paddedButton.setPadding(new Insets(3));
      paddedButton.getChildren().add(details);


    }

    /** places an details button in the row only if the row is not empty. */
    @Override protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);
      if (!empty) {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(paddedButton);
      } else {
        setGraphic(null);
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet of code:

```
actionCol.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Person, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty) {
                Button details = new Button("details");
                details.setOnAction(e ->{Person person= (Person)getTableRow().getItem(); System.out.println(person.getFirstName()+", "+person.getLastName());});
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                setGraphic(details);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            }

        }

    });
```

**Edit**: to avoid casting you can use this:

```
 details.setOnAction(e ->{int  index = getTableRow().getIndex();
 Person person= getTableView().getItems().get(index);
System.out.println(person.getFirstName()+", "+person.getLastName());});
```

Answer (score 1):

Person somePersone=  table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();